# android and JSON(how to create own jSon)?

Tags: android, json

i want to know how can i create JSON like geonames api do for findNearbyWiki instead using wiki data i want to define my own data. but i do not know how. i type json array and name it a.json. i upload my a.json in server...but it cannot be view.. 
here my json file

```
{"geonames":
[
{"summary":"Universiti Teknologi Malaysia (University of Technology Malaysia, UTM) is the oldest public engineering and technological university in Malaysia. The university specialises in technical studies, with separate faculties for Education, Pure Sciences, Management, and Human Resources Development (...)",
"distance":"0.0185",
"rank":90,
"title":"Universiti Teknologi Malaysia",
"wikipediaUrl":"en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universiti_Teknologi_Malaysia",
"elevation":26,
"countryCode":"MY",
"lng":103.641486,
"feature":"landmark",
"lang":"en",
"lat":1.559034
}
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use JsonObject and JsonArray class to put all the information in object and then call toString method on the main JsonObject. That would do this for you.

Comment: sorry does this mean i have to save all in .java file then upload to server?

Comment: no, you need not to save any object toString Method would give you String which you can use to send to the server.

Comment: can you explain a bit more :) im still new in java and android development :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSONObject](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html).

> The put methods add or replace values in an object. For example,

```
myString = new JSONObject().put("JSON", "Hello, World!").toString();
produces the string {"JSON": "Hello, World"}.
```

Comment: i wrote what you give me. do i have to save it in java? the server seem cannot view the file .. it pop out save file window ....

Comment: Yes that is java, and I don't think I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray geonames = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject item = new JSONObject();
    item.put("summary", "Universiti Teknologi Malaysia (University of Technology Malaysia, UTM) is the oldest public engineering and technological university in Malaysia. The university specialises in technical studies, with separate faculties for Education, Pure Sciences, Management, and Human Resources Development (...)");
    item.put("distance", 0.0185f);
    item.put("rank", "90");
    item.put("title", "Universiti Teknologi Malaysia");
    item.put("wikipediaUrl", "en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universiti_Teknologi_Malaysia");
    item.put("elevation", "26");
    item.put("countryCode", "MY");
    item.put("lng", 103.641486f);
    item.put("lang", "en");
    item.put("feature", "landmark");
    item.put("lat", 1.559034f);
    geonames.put(item);
    mainObject.put("geonames", geonames);
    String jsonString = mainObject.toString();
```

This is exactly what you need

Comment: now i see a bit. but my condition is i want to put this data online then call it to save on my JSONarray .